# How to make a figure span on two columns in a scientific paper?

Tags: floats, two-column, starred-version

If I just try to set the figure's size to `0.9\textwidth` my figure will just end up on the right column, sized to be two-columns wide.

Has anyone done this before?

Comment: I think we need a minimal example of what you are doing. There are lots of possible variations here. Did you try `\begin{figure*}`, for example?

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks. I thought adding an * only removed the figure's numbering?

Comment: You're confused with equation*

Comment: `figure*` and `table*` are two column figures and tables, respectively.

Comment: I had a similar problem, in `\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}`--but using `figure*[width=\textwidth]` sends it to the bottom of the document, not breaking the columns.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

From the TUG [faq](http://texfaq.org/FAQ-widefigs): use the starred versions `figure*` and `table*`. Unfortunately, they're somewhat limited in positioning.

Also, the same solution applies to equations. Just include them in a `figure*` environment. But I don't recommend doing this: it will look ugly and confusing. For an example, see [this paper](http://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevA.58.883). (sorry, I couldn't find an example in arXiv)

Comment: How are they limited in positioning? You don't want to put a full-width figure midway down the page, right?

Comment: @Will, true, but you can't put them at the bottom of a page, either, which you may reasonably want to do. http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=2colfloat

Comment: Me? No! But someone might conceivably need to, and I think it's a little dangerous to actually make it impossible to do so.

Comment: **@Lev**: Oh, I didn't remember that double-width floats can't appear at `[b]`! **@araujorns**: I know of some journals that can make full-width equations across double cols, effectively splitting the page in four; seems like cuted and midfloat can do this. I wouldn't use it for figures, however.

Comment: This is a screencapture of the mentioned equation example for those who cannot access it: https://i.imgur.com/pAtbpzL.png

Comment: Is there an equivalent option for listing?

Answer (score 7):

What about using the code below?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twocolumn,english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,tableposition=top]{caption}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{cuted}

\title{Two column document with figure underneath title}
\author{abhijit8}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{strip}
    \centering\noindent
    \rule{0.75\linewidth}{0.5\linewidth}
    \captionof{figure}{\blindtext}
\end{strip}

\blindtext[2]

\begin{strip}
    \centering\noindent
    \rule{0.75\linewidth}{0.5\linewidth}
    \captionof{figure}{\blindtext}
\end{strip}

\medskip
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \rule{0.75\linewidth}{0.5\linewidth}
    \captionof{figure}{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog}
\end{minipage}

\medskip
\blindtext[4]
\end{document}
```

It is from http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=10661#p41194 and works like a charm for me.

Comment: Since the example is not minimal, it may be helpful to note that the packages that are mandatory here are cuted (which provides the strip environment) and caption (which provides captionof).