# figure span to one column on double column page

Tags: floats, two-column

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make a figure span on two columns in a scientific paper?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3173/how-to-make-a-figure-span-on-two-columns-in-a-scientific-paper)

1. I want my figures to span to whole page width while on double
   column page, I am using `subfloat`, how to do that?
2. I want the figures to appear at the top of a specific page. How
   can I address that?

Answer (score 36):

In `twocolumn` mode, the `figure*` environment stretches over the entire page width, and necessarily prints the figure at the top of the page. Here is a minimal example highlighting this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1-2]
\section{Second section}
\lipsum[3]
\begin{figure*}
  \centering \includegraphics{figure}
  \caption{This is a figure caption}
\end{figure*}
\lipsum[4]
\section{Last section}
\lipsum[5-10]
\end{document}
```

[`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) was used to produce dummy text *Lorem Ipsum* style, while the `demo` option to [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) allows for 150pt x 100pt black rectangles of images, even if they do not exist (remove this option in your document).

---

The above option does not offer much control over the placement of the figure, since it will necessarily end up at the top. There is not much that can be done to get away from this, apart from breaking the two-column mode to allow floating figures. This start-stop of multicolumn environments are possible when using the [`multicol` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol). It provides the `multicols` environment

```
\begin{multicols}{<n>}
  ...
\end{multicols}
```

that typesets its contents in `<n>` evenly spaced columns (yielding a similar output to `twocolumn` mode if `<n>` is chosen as `2`).

Comment: The page on which the figure will go can be chosen by inserting the `figure*` environment between paragraphs that fall in the preceding page.

Answer (score 9):

Small amendment. If you want your illustration to span over entire page width, add `width` option to `\includegraphics` as shown below:

```
\begin{figure*}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figure}
  \caption{This is a figure caption}
\end{figure*}
```

PS: I assume that other details of importing picture are described in the 1st anwswer to this post.

Comment: i need to put two figures there instead of one figure . how to do this?

Comment: for including two figures i am trying this  \begin{figure*}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{1.PNG}
  \caption{This is a figure caption}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{2.PNG}
  \caption{This is a figure caption}
\end{figure*}  but it is not adjusting picture in a row