# How do I put a wide figure on the top of the first page of a two-column paper?

Tags: floats, two-column

I'd like my academic paper to have a page-width-spanning figure right underneath the title. How do I do this? Whenever I try using `\begin{figure*}...\end{figure*}` with the figure at the start of my paper, it always pushes it to the second page, no matter what combination of `h, t, !` arguments I put.

To be clear, I want something like this: [figure span to one column on double column page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34063/figure-span-to-one-column-on-double-column-page)

but I want my figure to be at the top of the FIRST page underneath the title. Does anyone have a minimum working example?

My document begins like this:

`\begin{document}
\maketitle
...`

Comment: Is this some kind of logo? Or is it a figure with a caption?

Comment: it's a figure with a caption

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may (mis)use the `title` field and insert a picture. To insert a caption, I used the `\captionof` from `caption` package as a floating figure there makes me uncomfortable!

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{caption}

\title[The title]{%
The Title\\[1em]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{logo}%
\captionof{figure}{This is a figure}
}
\author{The Author}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

To avoid trouble with headers or bookmarks use

```
 \title[The Title]{The Title\\[1em] 
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{logo}
  \captionof{figure}{This is a figure}
  }
```

as suggested by Gonzalo.

Answer (score 10):

This way:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{lipsum} % provides just dummy text

\begin{document}

\twocolumn[{\begin{figure}[H]
\setlength{\linewidth}{\textwidth}
\setlength{\hsize}{\textwidth}
\centering
\rule{10cm}{5cm} % this is your image
\caption{My first float}
\end{figure}}]

\lipsum % provides just dummy text

\end{document}
```

How does it work:

- The command `\twocolumn` initializes twocolumn mode. It has an optional argument that gets typeset as a "header" in the onecolumn mode.
- In this header we put a float placed `H`ere (please, never use `H` specifier elsewhere).
- Inside the float, we have to convince LaTeX that it's a wide figure, by correctly redefining the two width parameters.

---

## Version with `\maketitle`

The difference is that instead of using the command `\twocolumn`, we add the figure into the command `\@maketitle` which is responsible for typesetting the title material.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{lipsum} % provides just dummy text

\title{MyTitle}
\author{Me the 1st}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\@maketitle{
  \begin{figure}[H]
  \setlength{\linewidth}{\textwidth}
  \setlength{\hsize}{\textwidth}
  \centering
  \rule{10cm}{5cm} % this is your image
  \caption{My first float}
  \end{figure}
}
\makeatother

\maketitle

\lipsum % provides just dummy text

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are right about mwe's. But the question said below the title. Without a mwe, it is hard to say which way they get the title! `:-)`

Comment: Hi @tohecz, sorry, I wasn't clear... I do have a `\maketitle`; I apologize my question wasn't clear. With a `\maketitle` above the `\twocolumn` code you suggested, I have a blank first page except for the title, and my desired figure appears on the top of the second page. any ideas?

Comment: @spadina I added a version that should work with `\maketitle`. If it does not work, please edit your question and provide a full [Minimal Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).