# Multiple figures span to one column on IEEE 2 column format

Tags: floats, two-column, overleaf

I am just following this [figure span to one column on double column page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34063/figure-span-to-one-column-on-double-column-page)  to span figures on a  two-column page but the difference instead of pasting one figure I need to put two and three figures here.

This is code for pasting a figure by spanning two columns

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1-2]
\section{Second section}
\lipsum[3]
\begin{figure*}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figure}
  \caption{This is a figure caption}
\end{figure*}
\lipsum[4]
\section{Last section}
\lipsum[5-10]
\end{document}
```

I want to this same but instead of one figure I want to put two and three figures. I tried this but it's not working. Can any one help?

```
 \begin{figure*}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{1.PNG}
  \caption{This is a figure caption}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{2.PNG}
  \caption{This is a figure caption}
\end{figure*}
```

see figure for clear requirements.
[image]

please try to help instead of passing comments that it's already been answered. The existing one didn't help me that's why I posted this.

Comment: Is each image supposed to get its own caption, do you want a shared caption for all three images or do you want subcaptions with a shared caption? Although about tables rather than about images, the following may be useful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/597566/134144

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose this solution, based on the `floatrow` package:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\DeclareFloatSeparators{Qquad}{\hskip4em}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}
\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Second section}
\lipsum[3]
\begin{figure*}

\floatsetup{floatrowsep=Qquad}
\begin{floatrow}
  \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{Ralph Steadman. Illustrations for \emph{Alice in Wonderland}}\label{Alice-Ralph}}{\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{AliceSteadman}}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{Yuri Norstein. \emph{Hedgehog in the fog}}\label{Hedgehog}}{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Hedgehog-in-the-fog}}\hskip4em
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{Max Ernst. \emph{Euclid}}\label{Ernst}}{\includegraphics{Euclid}}
\end{floatrow}
\end{figure*}
\lipsum[4]

\section{Last section}
\lipsum[5-10]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since both IEEE and floatrow use custom captions, this may not be a good idea.  Don't mess with IEEE captions.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: As far as I know, the only thing that floatrow does is to fix the caption width

Comment: It can also move them to entirely different locations.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403661/how-to-prevent-floatrow-from-moving-the-caption  (OTOH, I believe the floatbox was created specifically to overcome this problem.)

Comment: @John they are using 2 figures in a row .. i need to place three figures

Comment: @Alex - What works for two tables will work for as many as will fit the page.

Comment: three figures are working but its not working for four figures .. how to do this

Comment: @Alex: I had not seen your last comment, sorry. If your question is bout the `floatrow` environment, you can specify the number of figures in a row as an optional argument, like this: `\begin{floatrow}[4] … \end{floatrow}`. Of course, the sum of the widths of these figure must not exceed `\textwidth`.