# How to put an image across double column?

Tags: graphics, floats, two-column, ieeetran

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make a figure span on two columns in a scientific paper?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3173/how-to-make-a-figure-span-on-two-columns-in-a-scientific-paper)

Below is a page using IEEE trans, how to put the image (see Figure 1) across two columns?

[image]

Comment: Check the [`ieeetran`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/ieeetran) manual for `figure*` environment.

Comment: Thanks @percusse, that works! Perhaps you could post your comment as an answer and at least I could accept it:)