# IEEEtran and using plots

Tags: two-column, plot, ieeetran

Within a IEEEtran 2 column document, 2 plots are too small concerning their width.

Should I place them (a) vertical or (b) interrupt the 2 column layout?

btw it will be submitted to a conference.

Has anyone received a feedback by a paper reviewer when using (a) or (b)?

Comment: Please see page 10, item D http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf

Comment: duplicate? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79742/how-to-put-an-image-accross-double-column  &  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3173/how-to-make-a-figure-span-on-two-columns-in-a-scientific-paper

Comment: thx to both comments - it was not about a HOW TO regarding latex commands. it is about experience concerning paper review (either given or received). the conf does not forbid the two options. once, i got a hint for (a) and once for (b). i was asking for authors / reviewers who faced already this issue. i was asking here cause the cluster of latex people is here higher in comparison to academia SE. in case of doubt, i am using the 2 column as 1 column option.

Comment: In my _opinion_ "experience concerning paper review" might be off-topic to this site and better suited for academia SE(some tex.sx members might be there as well and latex is also known in academia). Incase you have specific question on tex/latex related Q's, you are welcome.