# How to make a figure spread over twocolumns?

Tags: floats, two-column, dimensions

I have the following figure:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amssymb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amssymb
\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont

\definecolor{pblue}{rgb}{0.13,0.13,1}
\definecolor{pgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{pred}{rgb}{0.9,0,0}
\definecolor{pgrey}{rgb}{0.46,0.45,0.48}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.4,0.4,0.4}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.6}
\definecolor{cyan}{rgb}{0.0,0.6,0.6}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{language=Java,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
  showspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,
  breaklines=true,
  showstringspaces=false,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  commentstyle=\color{pgreen},
  keywordstyle=\color{pblue},
  stringstyle=\color{pred},
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  moredelim=[il][\textcolor{pgrey}]{$$},
  moredelim=[is][\textcolor{pgrey}]{\%\%}{\%\%}
}

\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}

%usar \nome{}
\newcommand{\ricardo}[1]{\colorbox{ForestGreen}{\color{white}\textsf{\textbf{Victor}}} \textcolor{ForestGreen}{#1}}
\newcommand{\victor}[1]{\colorbox{NavyBlue}{\color{white}\textsf{\textbf{Ricardo}}} \textcolor{NavyBlue}{#1}}
\newcommand{\helder}[1]{\colorbox{Plum}{\color{white}\textsf{\textbf{Helder}}} \textcolor{Plum}{#1}}

\definecolor{ShadowColor}{RGB}{30,150,190}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\Cshadowbox{\VerbBox\@Cshadowbox}
\def\@Cshadowbox#1{%
  \setbox\@fancybox\hbox{\fbox{#1}}%
  \leavevmode\vbox{%
    \offinterlineskip
    \dimen@=\shadowsize
    \advance\dimen@ .5\fboxrule
    \hbox{\copy\@fancybox\kern.5\fboxrule\lower\shadowsize\hbox{%
      \color{ShadowColor}\vrule \@height\ht\@fancybox \@depth\dp\@fancybox \@width\dimen@}}%
    \vskip\dimexpr-\dimen@+0.5\fboxrule\relax
    \moveright\shadowsize\vbox{%
      \color{ShadowColor}\hrule \@width\wd\@fancybox \@height\dimen@}}}
\makeatother

\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc
  % IEEE Computer Society needs nocompress option
  % requires cite.sty v4.0 or later (November 2003)
  \usepackage[nocompress]{cite}
\else
  % normal IEEE
  \usepackage{cite}
\fi

% correct bad hyphenation here
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\let\c@listing\c@lstlisting}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de tipos. Lorem Ipsum sobreviveu não só a cinco séculos, como também ao salto para a editoração eletrônica, permanecendo essencialmente inalterado. Se popularizou na década de 60, quando a Letraset lançou decalques contendo passagens de Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente quando passou a ser integrado a softwares de editoração eletrônica como Aldus PageMaker.

Ao contrário do que se acredita, Lorem Ipsum não é simplesmente um texto randômico. Com mais de 2000 anos, suas raízes podem ser encontradas em uma obra de literatura latina clássica datada de 45 AC. Richard McClintock, um professor de latim do Hampden-Sydney College na Virginia, pesquisou uma das mais obscuras palavras em latim, consectetur, oriunda de uma passagem de Lorem Ipsum, e, procurando por entre citações da palavra na literatura clássica, descobriu a sua indubitável origem. Lorem Ipsum vem das seções 1.10.32 e 1.10.33 do "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (Os Extremos do Bem e do Mal), de Cícero, escrito em 45 AC. Este livro é um tratado de teoria da ética muito popular na época da Renascença. A primeira linha de Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet..." vem de uma linha na seção 1.10.32.

Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de tipos. Lorem Ipsum sobreviveu não só a cinco séculos, como também ao salto para a editoração eletrônica, permanecendo essencialmente inalterado. Se popularizou na década de 60, quando a Letraset lançou decalques contendo passagens de Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente quando passou a ser integrado a softwares de editoração eletrônica como Aldus PageMaker.

\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=1.0\columnwidth]{img/FrameworkTaaS.png}
        \caption{Framework TaaS (Colocar as referências que eu utilizei)}
        \label{fig:frameworkTaaS}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}

Ao contrário do que se acredita, Lorem Ipsum não é simplesmente um texto randômico. Com mais de 2000 anos, suas raízes podem ser encontradas em uma obra de literatura latina clássica datada de 45 AC. Richard McClintock, um professor de latim do Hampden-Sydney College na Virginia, pesquisou uma das mais obscuras palavras em latim, consectetur, oriunda de uma passagem de Lorem Ipsum, e, procurando por entre citações da palavra na literatura clássica, descobriu a sua indubitável origem. Lorem Ipsum vem das seções 1.10.32 e 1.10.33 do "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (Os Extremos do Bem e do Mal), de Cícero, escrito em 45 AC. Este livro é um tratado de teoria da ética muito popular na época da Renascença. A primeira linha de Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet..." vem de uma linha na seção 1.10.32.

Ao contrário do que se acredita, Lorem Ipsum não é simplesmente um texto randômico. Com mais de 2000 anos, suas raízes podem ser encontradas em uma obra de literatura latina clássica datada de 45 AC. Richard McClintock, um professor de latim do Hampden-Sydney College na Virginia, pesquisou uma das mais obscuras palavras em latim, consectetur, oriunda de uma passagem de Lorem Ipsum, e, procurando por entre citações da palavra na literatura clássica, descobriu a sua indubitável origem. Lorem Ipsum vem das seções 1.10.32 e 1.10.33 do "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (Os Extremos do Bem e do Mal), de Cícero, escrito em 45 AC. Este livro é um tratado de teoria da ética muito popular na época da Renascença. A primeira linha de Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet..." vem de uma linha na seção 1.10.32.

Ao contrário do que se acredita, Lorem Ipsum não é simplesmente um texto randômico. Com mais de 2000 anos, suas raízes podem ser encontradas em uma obra de literatura latina clássica datada de 45 AC. Richard McClintock, um professor de latim do Hampden-Sydney College na Virginia, pesquisou uma das mais obscuras palavras em latim, consectetur, oriunda de uma passagem de Lorem Ipsum, e, procurando por entre citações da palavra na literatura clássica, descobriu a sua indubitável origem. Lorem Ipsum vem das seções 1.10.32 e 1.10.33 do "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (Os Extremos do Bem e do Mal), de Cícero, escrito em 45 AC. Este livro é um tratado de teoria da ética muito popular na época da Renascença. A primeira linha de Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet..." vem de uma linha na seção 1.10.32.

Ao contrário do que se acredita, Lorem Ipsum não é simplesmente um texto randômico. Com mais de 2000 anos, suas raízes podem ser encontradas em uma obra de literatura latina clássica datada de 45 AC. Richard McClintock, um professor de latim do Hampden-Sydney College na Virginia, pesquisou uma das mais obscuras palavras em latim, consectetur, oriunda de uma passagem de Lorem Ipsum, e, procurando por entre citações da palavra na literatura clássica, descobriu a sua indubitável origem. Lorem Ipsum vem das seções 1.10.32 e 1.10.33 do "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (Os Extremos do Bem e do Mal), de Cícero, escrito em 45 AC. Este livro é um tratado de teoria da ética muito popular na época da Renascença. A primeira linha de Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet..." vem de uma linha na seção 1.10.32.

Ao contrário do que se acredita, Lorem Ipsum não é simplesmente um texto randômico. Com mais de 2000 anos, suas raízes podem ser encontradas em uma obra de literatura latina clássica datada de 45 AC. Richard McClintock.



\end{document}
```

Compilation Result:

[image]

How do you adjust the figure so that it occupies the space of two columns? Similar to red region.

Comment: I'm going to edit your post a little, if you don't mind... *expand* is quite a powerful word in the world of TeX and friends :)

Comment: `\begin{figure*} picture \end{figure*}`

Comment: Hello everyone! @cmhughes thank you so much for editing my question :) @ Christian Hupfer I did the test by entering an asterisk in figure, but it did not work.

Comment: This question seems to be a dupplicate of  [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3173/how-to-make-a-figure-span-on-two-columns-in-a-scientific-paper)

Comment: `figure*` specifies a two-column figure.  but two-column figures can be placed (automatically) only at the top of a page, not in the middle as your diagram indicates.

Answer (score 3):

Beside of the `figure*` float, that have the already mentioned inconvenient that should be in the top of a page, you can use `cuted` to show the figure at any place on double-column
pages. Note that `cuted` is not fully compatible with floats, so you should use some package as `capt-of` for captions without a `figure` environment.  Note also that text flow in this way is not

> left top → (image) →  left bottom → right top → (image) → right bottom

but

> left top → right top → (image) → left bottom → right bottom

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{cuted,capt-of}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{strip}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-a}
\captionof{figure}{Framework TaaS ... }
\end{strip}

\lipsum[3-50]
\end{document}
```