# Placing a figure in one-column within a two-column document

Tags: page-breaking

This is the code in which I have the texts in two-column mode,  but I want the figure to be placed in one-column  without a page-break

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\onecolumn\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{Capture.PNG}
  \caption{A system}
  \label{fig:1}

\end{figure}
\twocolumn
```

Comment: I would say that this is a duplicate of this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3173/how-to-make-a-figure-span-on-two-columns-in-a-scientific-paper ... (Didn't marked as dupplicate but found in two steps by searching "two column figure"...). My comment is just an advice of searching before posting a question. Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 2):

You mean something like this?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \twocolumn
    \lipsum
    \begin{figure*}
        \includegraphics{example-image}
    \end{figure*}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

to get:

[image]

> Finally, welcome to TeX.se. Next time when you post a question, please post a MWE so that it will not only help the users but also attracts many people to answer your question.

Comment: You're right I Exactly same type in ieeetrans class

Comment: @ProsenjitPaulBappy you are welcome, if you find the answer helpful, consider accepting it by clicking the tick-mark in the top-left below the voting button.

Comment: you have used `figure*` with `[ht]` which is the same as `[t]` as `[h]` is not supported, so the effect of the optional argument is to prevent the use of `[p]` and so make it much more likely the figure goes to the end of the document

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I just copied the float argument from the OP's snippet. Could you please tell me what I must do here? should I just change it to `t` instead?

Comment: @Raaja just delete `[ht]`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks for the remark and it's done.