# Image inserting issue in Article writing

Tags: diagrams, column-width, wide-image

[image]

Hey guys, I am writing an article using documentclass{ieeeaccess} document in two columns. But I want this image to appear in two columns width instead of in one column. Kindly help me with this.

Comment: You can use the `strip` environment, from the `cuted` package, to temporarily be in single column mode.

Comment: See also: [How to make a figure span on two columns in a scientific paper?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3173/134144)

Comment: If you want to put the figure at the bottom of the page, the `stfloats` package is intended to do that.  More possibilities are mentioned in answers to this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107270

Comment: In a two column paper `\begin{figure*} ... \end{figure*} will put the figure at the top of the next page spanning both columns.