# Overfull \hbox when \textwidth exceeds \columnwidth while using \includegraphics in a 2 column template

Tags: width, includegraphics, textwidth, column-width

I have a 2 column template in Overleaf.

I would like the figure to span both the columns (otherwise the text in the figure becomes too small).

I tried the following script:

```
 \begin{figure}
 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Fig1.png}
 \end{figure}
```

It renders the following result:

[image]

The black line on the right is there because of `Overfull \hbox`.

Interestingly, the `Overfull \hbox` happens whenever the `\includegraphics` width exceeds the `\columnwidth`.

As an example, using `\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Fig1.png}` renders the following image:

[image]

Whereas, `\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{Fig1.png}` renders correctly:

[image]

I have worked on it for hours but to no avail. Please guide me if/when free.

Comment: Have you tried using `\begin{figure*}\centering\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Fig1.png}\end{figure*}` ?

Comment: @imnothere It worked! Thank you so much!! Could you please add it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Well, it's really just https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3180 :-)