# How do I properly insert images with full width in a two column format

Tags: graphics, overleaf, wide-image

I am using a two column document using

```
\usepackage{twocolceurws}
```

I have an image which I want to place after a particular section. Here's the issue - The text above the image is like about half a section. So, I want the text to wrap around equally in both sections and then the image. Here's an image describing it

[image]

I have tried using float, but that places the image over the text. I have also tried figure*, but that puts all the images in a new page, but I want them in the same page. I also tried the fullwidth package, but can't seem to get it to work without errors

I am using Overleaf, if that makes any difference

Comment: Try [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3173/how-to-make-a-figure-span-on-two-columns-in-a-scientific-paper). There's also a reference to a short answer in [FAQ](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-widefigs).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: is twocolceurws (which is not a package I have seen before) a requirement, or are standard two column systems also a possibility? also what is the reading order in your sketch, is the second block bottom left or top right? As always, your question would be clearer if you provided a test document and described what you wanted its output to be.

Comment: @Celdor I had seen that, the figure* did not work, but the second comment works! Just 1 more slight issue, it's inserting a random charachter "7" in between multiple strips... I cannot figure out why...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it's not a requirement, just a package another contributor added for making the format, we can certainly change that. I'm sorry if the reading is confusing, it's top left -> top right and then the image. The question is more or less solved, but I appreciate your reply, thanks!

Comment: @Destux You could try to use [stfloats](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/stfloats), which adds optional ``[b]` argument to `float*`. It then should place your image at the bottom. I don't know if it's compatible with `twocolceurws`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
    \begin{strip}
        \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
        \end{center}        
    \end{strip}
    \lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This is working, thanks, but there seems to be an issue where when adding multiple strips, there is a character "7" in between those strips... any ideas how I can workaround with that?